# How to run pre-integration-test before integration-test across all modules in a multi-module project?

Tags: continuous-integration, integration-testing, maven-3, maven-failsafe-plugin, maven-cargo

I have a simple multi-module project

```
Project:    
 - moduleA
 - moduleB
 - moduleC
 - integration
 - parent pom
```

I have defined a tomcat9x cargo plugin in the `integration` project.

I have added the `failsafe` plugin to the parent pom.

The problem I'm having is that the integration tests for each module are attempting to run before the `pre-integration-test` target in the integration project starts up tomcat.

I also tried moving the `failsafe` plugin to be only in the `integration` project, but then none of the module's individual integration tests run at all.

**How can I ensure that `pre-integration-test` is executed prior to `integration-test` across the entire project?**